# Implementing a progressive design for all browsers including IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css

I find it hard to please the whole world on this, but on my website, I have an advertisement with google adsense loaded in async mode. When any of my webpages load in a modern browser, the text comes up relatively fast, however on Internet Explorer 7 and slow mobile phones (like my android), there's a different story. Part of the website header loads but the word "Advertisement" appears on screen way too early on those browsers, but on modern browsers, all text appears at the same time. The advertisements are always floated to the left inside a div via css `#DIVID{float:left}`.

I'm not sure if it is just the older browsers themselves that have rendering problems, but I'm trying to make my site work for all.

Are there any HTML coding tricks I can use to make all text content (minus styles and minus javascript) appear all at the same time on all browsers? I think I need a special tag for IE 7 to make it cooperate but I don't know which tag?

Comment: You are really supporting IE7? It is like 0.35% of the market... Yikes. So hide the div and add a rule to show it at some point. Without know specifics it is hard to help give you a solution.

Comment: I want to support everyone, especially considering my site is a site mainly of showing pictures. Hiding elements after they have loaded (such as the image containing the word "loading") is what I want to avoid as it wrecks google's webmaster guidelines.